# How to Read Json array values from file

Tags: java, arrays, json, feed

```
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
```

When I use the above code, it shows the error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
```

Please anyone suggest any method to overcome this error or any other way to read json value form a file in Java (Desktop application).

Comment: Can you show us your JSON in file? As your Exception it self shows that you don't have JSONArray in your file.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for get json value in string format from file

```
public String loadJSONFromFile() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("yourfilename.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

JsonObject is a child of a JsonArray, so as per my suggestion use like this

```
final JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(obj); //obj is your JsonObject
```

and you can get JsonObject from array like

```
jsonArray.getJSONObject(0); //0 is index of your JsonObject in JsonArray
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of the file.

It seems that the content is not an array, but a json object.

Open the file with a text editor. If the content is something like:

```
{   // First character
    ...  content here
}   // Last character
```

it is an object, if it is similar to

```
[   // First character
    ... content here
]   // Last character
```

it is an array.

If you need to read an object you need to change your code as follow:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
```

This `obj` is of JsonObject type, so change that line to

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)obj;
```